# Slideshow software for Apple II?

Tags: apple-ii, graphics, software-recommendation

I'd like to do a presentation using my Apple //e as the video generator. Is there any good "slideshow" or presentation software for the Apple //e other than writing a BASIC program to draw on the HGR screen.

Preferably I'd like to author the images and/or text on my PC, and the ADTPro a disk to the Apple //e to show off the slideshow.

Understanding the limitations of disk size, I expect the slideshow to be mostly text slides, interspersed with graphics. I'm just curious if there's anything out there already for generating graphics and text slides, and displaying them in sequence controlled with the keyboard, or if I just need to brush off my Applesoft BASIC books.

Comment: There's a slide show program in fhpack that you can use as a base (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNBSd1oGGaU). It scans a ProDOS directory and displays compressed or uncompressed images based on the file type. If you were planning to have lots of images, the compression may also be of use, though that's a bit more experimental.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need ProDOS, [Frame-Up](http://beagle.applearchives.com/the_software/vintage_beagle_bros_softwar/frame-up.html) by Beagle Brothers might suit your needs.

The image there is a little hard to read, so here is the feature list:

> - PROFESSIONAL PRESENTATIONS: Frame-Up lets you use your Apple to make displays of Hi-Res, Lo-Res and Text frames on large-screen or standard
>     monitors.
> - HIGH SPEED: Frame-Up Is FAST, allowing you to display Hi-Res Images In 2 1/2 seconds, more than FOUR TIMES faster than normal.
> - FORWARD & REVERSE: Frame-Up allows you to move through a presentation in forward or REVERSE order (under keyboard or paddle
>     control), to SKIP any frame, and to instantly RE-ARRANGE the order of
>     images.
> - INCREASED DISK STORAGE: Store up to 17 Hi-Res or 136 Lo-Res/Text frames (or a combination of types) on a single disk. Frame-Up works
>     equally-well with one or two drives.
> - UNLIMITED SHOW LENGTH: Frame-Up allows you to link any number of disks together without interrupting your presentation.
> - UNATTENDED OPERATION: Frame-Up lets you present shows that may be left unattended, with each image individually timed to remain on the
>     screen from 1 TO 99 SECONDS. Frame-Up's professional design includes
>     automatic recovery from power outages in Unattended Mode.
> - TEXT SCREEN EDITOR: Unlike other display utilities, Frame-Up lets you display TEXT IMAGES as well as Hi- and Lo-Res graphics. Frame-Up
>     includes on EDITOR that allows you to create black-and-white text
>     frames. You can even odd type "live" on the screen during
>     presentatlons. (Frame-Up does not include software for creating HI- or
>     Lo-Res graphics.)

Comment: Hope it helps. I bought Frame-Up as a kid. It was lots of fun - it comes with a text animated fireworks demo IIRC. And it was worth it just for the PEEKS & POKES chart and stickers!

Comment: Note: I tested the Frame-Up disk that I linked to, and the tutorial doesn't work unless the image has volume number 11. The easiest way to do this is convert it to 2MG and use CiderPress to set the volume number to 11.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to make use of these:

http://www.appleoldies.ca/azgraphics33/applevu.htm

(You'll need to download the Aztec C compiler at the top of this page : http://www.appleoldies.ca/azgraphics33/index.htm)

http://www.applefritter.com/content/apple-ii-hi-res-pictures

Answer (score 3):

For the "converting images" part, there is [bmp2dhr](http://www.appleoldies.ca/bmp2dhr/) to convert (and dither) images in [BMP format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) to the various Apple formats, including double hires on the IIe. Youtube recordings of such a slideshow loading from disk can be found [here](http://www.bytecellar.com/2015/02/07/bmp2dhr-the-best-apple-ii-graphics-youve-seen-this-week/) and [here](http://www.bytecellar.com/2015/03/22/bmp2dhgr-revisited-a-slideshow-running-on-real-metal/). I'm not sure what program he is running to load the images.

I'd assume that each image takes a lot of disk space, so you'll be limited in the number of slides, and if you have a lot of slides with just text, that is maybe not what you are looking for.

Comment: He's using DHISHOW to load the images: http://www.appleoldies.ca/cc65/docs/dhgr/dhishow.pdf